# How to set up watir-rspec from scratch

Tags: ruby, rspec, automated-tests, watir

I am struggling to set-up watir-rspec framework for my web-project for ui-testing. 
(https://github.com/watir/watir-rspec)

Here are the steps I took:

- Installed Ruby 2.0.0
- Installed watir-rspec gem
- Did watir-rspec install on my project's ui-test/ directory
- Made example_spec.rb file into ui-test/spec folder and copied the example from the documentation into the file.
- Tried to run it from cmd: rspec spec/example_spec.rb

Here is the error I am getting:

```
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/watir-rspec-1.1.0/lib/watir/rspec/helper.rb:4:in `<module:Helper>': uninitialized constant Watir::RSpec::Helper::Forwardable (NameError)
  from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/watir-rspec-1.1.0/lib/watir/rspec/helper.rb:3:in `<class:RSpec>'
  from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/watir-rspec-1.1.0/lib/watir/rspec/helper.rb:2:in `<module:Watir>'
  from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/watir-rspec-1.1.0/lib/watir/rspec/helper.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
  from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
  from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
  from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/watir-rspec-1.1.0/lib/watir/rspec.rb:47:in `<top (required)>'
  from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:110:in `require'
  from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:110:in `rescue in require'
  from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:35:in `require'
  from C:/wamp/www/smart/tests/ui-test/spec/spec_helper.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
  from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
  from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
  from C:/wamp/www/smart/tests/ui-test/spec/example_spec.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
  from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:896:in `load'
  from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:896:in `block in load_spec_files'
  from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:896:in `each'
  from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:896:in `load_spec_files'
  from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:22:in `run'
  from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:80:in `run'
  from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:17:in `block in autorun'
```

What steps am I missing? Am I even trying to run the test correctly?

Obviously I am kindof new to this whole thing - any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you do a `bundle install`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception you are seeing appears to be watir/rspec doing a `extend Forwardable` with the assumption that Forwardable had already been required. Adding a `require 'forwardable'` will solve this problem.

Once that was fixed, I got unintialized constant Watir::Browser exceptions. It appears that watir/rspec does not automatically require watir for you. You need to manually do that, hence the adding of the `require 'watir'` line.

In summary, following the steps you did, I found I had to make 2 changes to the spec_helper.rb. At the top of the file (ie before the `require watir/rspec` line) add the lines:

```
require 'forwardable'
require 'watir'
```

Comment: These problems are now fixed in `watir-rspec` version `1.1.2` which i just released!